# Drool - Spark performance issue

Tags: java, performance, apache-spark, configuration, drools

I am using Spark streaming for processing multiple CSV files. File validations changes often due to downstream systems. For this we decided to explore Apache Drools. Before using Drools, large size file was getting process in seconds. After adding few rules in Drool, performance has degraded significantly. For a 5MB file system it is taking 3-4 mins to process. I am new to Spark and Drools, want to understand how these both can be used together in Java. I have come across multiple answers but couldn't understand how I can use it.

Below is code:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class DroolConfig {

private KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

private KieFileSystem getKieFileSystem() throws IOException {
    KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
    kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("drlrules/rules.drl"));
    return kieFileSystem;

}

@Bean
public KieContainer getKieContainer() throws IOException {
    log.info("Container created...");
    getKieRepository();
    KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(getKieFileSystem());
    kb.buildAll();
    KieModule kieModule = kb.getKieModule();
    KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());
    return kContainer;

}

private void getKieRepository() {
    final KieRepository kieRepository = kieServices.getRepository();
    kieRepository.addKieModule(new KieModule() {
        public ReleaseId getReleaseId() {
            return kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId();
        }
    });
}

@Bean
public KieSession getKieSession() throws IOException {
    log.info("session created...");
    return getKieContainer().newKieSession();

}
```

Validation file:

```
@Autowired
private KieSession session;
.....
javaRDD1.collect().forEach(col -> {
        if(idx[0] > 0) {
            clientModel.setCsvLine(Arrays.asList(col));
            clientModel.setFileName(file.getName());

            FactHandle handle = session.insert(clientModel);
            session.fireAllRules();
            session.delete(handle);
        }

        idx[0]++;
    });
```

Comment: JBoss Drools, I presume, not apache?

Comment: Also are you actually sending each individual _line_ through the rules individually? That seems extremely inefficient.

Comment: Please post an example rule as well, or else we won't be able to tell if your rules are an additional source of inefficiency.